# What is a better way to be structuring our python repositories?

Tags: python

I'm part of a team working with several private Python repositories. Our team has experience writing code with Python but not so much with building and deploying large-scale applications using Python, so I am asking for advice on how to set up large projects better.

We've run into several issues with build and deployment so far, and we believe that these issues have to do with how we're setting up our projects. We work on several different Python services, each in its own repository, although there are cross-repo dependencies.

A typical repository for us looks like this:

```
# `foo-bar` repository
foo-bar/
|- .github/
|- tests/
|- foo_bar_main.py # main() loop is here
|- src/ # utils are here
|-- setup.py
|-- foo_bar/
|---- foo_utils.py # may be referenced by other repos  
|- .gitignore
|- Dockerfile
|- requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt` for `foo` might look like this:

```
async-timeout==4.0.2
dnspython==2.4.1
httpx==0.24.1
numpy==1.25.1
pandas==2.0.3
pathlib==1.0.1
pydantic==1.10.2
pymongo==4.4.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
redis==4.6.0
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
tenacity==8.2.2
tzdata==2023.3

-e git+https://${GH_PAT}@github.com/company/foo-bar@main#egg=foo_bar&subdirectory=src # foo-bar references itself
-e git+https://${GH_PAT}@github.com/company/baz@main#egg=baz&subdirectory=src
```

`setup.py` for `foo` might look like:

```
import setuptools
import os

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../requirements.txt")) as f:
    dependencies = [line for line in f.read().splitlines() if not line.startswith("-e")]

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../README.md")) as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="foo-bar",
    install_requires=dependencies,
    ...
)
```

When we build code locally, we typically run the following steps:

1. Remove the `-e` lines from `requirements.txt`
2. Run `pip install -r requirements.txt`
3. Manually install the other repo dependencies (`pip install -e ../baz/src`)

When we build code for deployment, we just include `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the Docker steps.

---

However, we started running into some problems. We noticed that when we do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it will re-clone the folder inside of the `src` dir, such that the final state looks like:

```
foo-bar/
|- .github/
|- tests/
|- src/
|-- setup.py
|-- foo_bar/
|---- foo_utils.py # may be referenced by other repos  
|---- foo-bar/
|------ src/
|-------- foo_bar/
|------ ... # has the entire recursive directory here
|- .gitignore
|- Dockerfile
|- requirements.txt
```

This has caused us some problems (ie. with `pytest` since each testfile exists twice in the directory).

What is the best way for us to set up our directories?

Right now we are just hacking around to make things work, but we need to set up these projects correctly pretty soon to avoid further grief.

Comment: I think you could put the setup.py outside of the src folder

Comment: Do note that `setup.py` is outdated. You might consider switching to `setuptools`'s current `pyproject.toml` interface, or migrating to a different modern build system, like poetry, hatch, flit, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We are aware that `pyproject.toml` is the new way but have not had the chance to migrate over.

Comment: I may not fully understand your needs, but typically, you should choose either a `requirements.txt` OR a `setup.py`/`pyproject.toml`, not both. I'm also a bit confused by the apparent circular reference within the `requirements.txt`. This might be the cause of your problems - if `foo-bar` is a package, you shouldn't be installing that package explicitly (i.e. in the `requirements.txt` file)... running `python setup.py install` or `pip install .` from the `foo-bar` root directory is sufficient.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

There are quite a few ways to manage and distribute packages with Python, due to it's flexibility. That's why guidelines are in place to try to have everyone working consistently.